# Getting XHTML from DRM EPUB

Tags: objective-c, ipad, adobe, epub, drm

I'm currently using the Adobe RMSDK to read DRM EPUBs. It renders an EPUB page as an image, and sends it back to be displayed on the device. I would really like to have access to the EPUBs XHTML, to display it in a webview. I have been able to unzip the EPUBs and browse the different chapters, but the content is still encrypted.

Is there anyone that have any idea how I can accomplish this?

I'm using Xcode 4.2 , Objective C/C++

Regards,
EZFrag

EDIT 1:
I already combed through the whole RMSDK, but was unable to find anything that could help me. I also couldn't find any online resource explaining what to do.

EDIT 2:
6th of March 2012

Woopy... "We" decided to create our own DRM system. This means we will strip out everything and anything related to Adobe...

Comment: ... Good lord... its messy. I have been ably to load the clean content using the ContentItterator... but again... I would really like to have the original xhtml... and not the displayed text itself