# How to get cover image from epub file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, epub

I required to display the cover image from shared epub file(Like iBooks and kindle).

Suppose I shared multiple book means unzip take long time.

Is it any alternative way?

I spend more time in Google. But I can not get solution.

please give some idea with sample code.

thanks in advance.,

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306629/getting-xhtml-from-drm-epub A dark, dark tunnel you're going down..

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Kavya: I tried Cover image URL from my server while get book information. Otherwise we have to unzip epub file and then get the content of cover image.

Comment: have you found specific steps to get cover image from unzipped epub?

Comment: Here is a step-by-step guide http://stackoverflow.com/a/34685183/517707

Answer (score 6):

You can unzip the file and goto OEBPS folder to look for an image file.

run this at command line

```
unzip abc.epub // replace the abc.epub file with your epub file path
```

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 0):

cover image will always be the first page to be displayed. So get the content of cover image from epub and try to display it