# fetch Cover Image from epub in ios

Tags: ios, epub, cover

I want to display Book Cover Image of epub file in my Reading table. In my iOS application I have  added "Open In" support for epub files. So when i navigate to my book reading app I want to show book's cover image in shelf first and then want to load that book. Please help me to fetch Cover Image from epub book in ios app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to unzip the ePub and parse the metadata.

1. Parse `META-INF/container.xml` and find the .OPF file path.
2. The .OPF file contains all that you need, a tag `meta` with name `cover` that refers to a tag `item`, this is the image cover.
3. You can copy this image to somewhere and delete the unzipped files.

PS: I am the creator of [FolioReaderKit](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit/) an ePub Reader and Parser written in Swift 2, this is where I get the book cover [FREpubParser.swift](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit/blob/master/Source/EPUBCore/FREpubParser.swift#L103). If you don't want to deal XML you can read the ePubs using it, it will also parse the metadata and exposes for you.

Comment: Thanks you ... I have followed your steps and it worked for me... Have you worked on epub3 reader?

Comment: I'm starting the implementation of epub3 on FolioReaderKit.

Comment: @Kavya FYI I have implemented ePub 3 support.

Comment: Yeah, free and Open Source :)

Comment: Have you created any SDK for audio epub books?

Comment: is this a rule that all epubs must follow? I see the following in an example `<meta name="cover" content="cover-image" />` will there always be this format?... i.e. there will always be an attribute content which will refer to the `id` in the manifest?